# looking for suggestions on complex table header

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I would like to have a table header that looks like the image shown below. 
Could somebody give me suggestions on how I would achieve this.
thanks.

winform, #c, .net 2.0

[ComplexHeader http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9a56a02c92.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9a56a02c92.jpg)

Comment: Is this for a web site, windows forms app, WPF app?

Comment: By "table", what control exactly are you referring to? A DataGridView?

Comment: Web site , Windows form or WPF? Exactly you need to be specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to implement a custom Column type that encapsulate the three sub-columns.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of anything built into the .NET 2.0 framework that will do the job. However, Telerik has a wonderful and richly features grid control that should do the trick:

http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/gridview.aspx